# Modified Mage_Sales_Model_Order

Tags: php, magento

I need guidance from you all..

I have this added method inside: Mage_Sales_Model_Order (it's in a local folder).

```
public function getShippingEmailAdd()
{
    $ShippingEmailAdd='';
    $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
    if (!isset($ShippingEmailAdd))
    {
       if (isset($postData['shipping:email'])) {
            $ShippingEmailAdd =$postData['shipping:email'];
        }else{
            $ShippingEmailAdd = 'lol@email.com';
        }
        // $shipment_data = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        // $ShippingEmailAdd = $shipment_data;
    }



    return $ShippingEmailAdd;
}
```

this method is focused on getting the shipping[email] input from the onepage checkout. and also added this one line under the method: samefile::sendNewOrderEmail()

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
            'emailadd' => $this->getShippingEmailAdd() <--- added line
        )
    );
```

so that I could use {{var emailadd}} in order_*.html templates. but I get nothing, what did I do wrong? and what would be the right approach to achieve my goal?

UPDATE as Requested:
this is the email input, coming from the shipment form which is part of the onepage checkout process:

```
<li>
            <div class="input-box">
                <label for="shipping:emailadd"><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" name="shipping[email]" id="shipping:emailadd" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="validate-email required-entry input-text" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <label for="shipping:emailadd"><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Email') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" name="shipping[emailconfirm]" id="shipping:emailconfirm" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="validate-email required-entry input-text" />
            </div>
        </li>
```

and again, what I'm aiming is to get the email field input after the checkout process has been sent and add the shipping[email] value to the Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getShippingEmailAdd() so that when I use it under the method age_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail() like this:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
            'emailadd' => $this->getShippingEmailAdd() <------ like this
        )
    );
```

so I can use it in the order_*.html email templates as {{var emailadd}}

that's it.

Answer (score 1):

`getShippingEmailAdd()` will return `''`

The code within the if statement will not executed.

```
$ShippingEmailAdd='';

if (!isset($ShippingEmailAdd))
{
    // remove your code from here
    $ShippingEmailAdd = 'executed';
}
else{
    $ShippingEmailAdd = 'not executed';
}

echo $ShippingEmailAdd;
```

You will test here http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Try

```
public function getShippingEmailAdd()
{
    $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (isset($postData['shipping:email'])) {  // <- double check your form field name
        $ShippingEmailAdd =$postData['shipping:email'];
    }else{
        $ShippingEmailAdd = 'lol@email.com';
    }

    return $ShippingEmailAdd;
}
```

Comment: It outputs the lol@email.com, hmmm...
by the way @R.S I have this `$shipment_data = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData();` it returns this ArrayObject when print_r($shipment_data) `Array ( [address_id] => 1680 [quote_id] => 467 [created_at] => 2010-06-09 16:12:39 [updated_at] => 2010-06-09 16:22:34 [customer_id] => [save_in_address_book] => 0 [customer_address_id] => [address_type] => shipping [email] => `

how do I get the value shipping[email] in $shipment_data? quite confuse.

trying another way, which was the commented line above.

Comment: Keep in mind that your are dealing will `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` ('order') and not 'Quote', this will not work if you try to resend email from admin. You may want to consider add a field to the order table.

Comment: well I don't think the one using it will resend qoutes using the admin, they're focuses on the email received. :/ 

so the to get the shipping[email], it must be this: `$shipment_data['shipping']['email']` right? or `$shipment_data->shipping['email']`? if I'm not mistaken.

*half-sleep because it's 10:31PM here.. xD

ok2 I get it, wew my arrays are getting a bit rusty.. xD

Comment: if I use the one you're giving, after submitting the checkout process. it redirects me back to the cart, inshort I can't checkout the items I  ordered, I think there's an error with the getData('email') and getEmail() hmm...

Comment: I think this one's the problem:
`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData();` because it's just returning an empty Array. are there other methods to getShippingAddress() input data?..

Comment: Sorry.. using `getData()` is normally for debugging it return an array of all the elements. The mangento way of doing it would be (so you dont have to check if array element exist) `$shipment_data = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()` then `$shipment_data->getData('email')` or `$shipment_data->getEmail()`

Comment: it returns nothing. just blank. why is that I don't get a value? is there another way to get the checkout data? aside from using this one `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()` because this one is returning nothing or empty.

Comment: is it possible that this line of code `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()` is deprecated?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? By default magento only have one email address. Could you add the HTML code for the email field name

Comment: Your value should be in $postData, you should use the field name and not the id Try print_r($postData); and print_r($postData['shipping']['email']);

Comment: the `print_r($postData)` returns nothing same goes with `$postData['shipping']['email']`, and the weird thing is when I did it this way: `$ShippingEmailAdd = $postData['shipping']['email'];` after submitting the onepage checkout form, it redirects me back to the cart page. Nothing gets send or anything just redirects me back.